# iPhone WSDL service using HTTP POST and GET Bindings

Tags: iphone, web-services, wsdl

I have a WSDL service that is working fine with .NET using HTTP POST Bindings, rather than using SOAP.  The HTTP Post request returns the raw XML for the objects etc. removing all the overhead of SOAP.

I would like to use this within the iPhone.  I have located the tool at wsdl2objc tool (http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/)  however it seems to only generate SOAP bindings which I don't use because I don't need the overhead.

What would be the best option for using WSDL HTTP POST Bindings within the iPhone OS?  It would be great if the wsdl2objc tool also supported the HTTP POST bindings however I don't see that happening soon.  I would rather have this code automatically generated for when the service changes etc.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I opted to use JSON instead of the WSDL service.

Comment: You can use [Objectify](http://tigerbears.com/objectify/) to automatically generate model objects from JSON requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are very few code generators around for this kind of thing.  For now I lumped with wsdl2objc but shrunk the size of the data being returned from the web service in a bid to make the XML smaller and more manageable. On a slower cellular connection that the iPhone sometimes has (2G etc.) I noticed slight improvement, but nothing worth an awards evening.